# How do I rotate a polygon around its center on mouse click?

Tags: opengl, rotation, shapes

I want to find out how I would be able to rotate my polygon around its center when I click a mouse button?

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //drawing a pentagon and coloring it.(using a polygon GL)
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);//Blue   
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f);//top point
    glColor3f(1, 0.5, 0);//Orange
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.3f, 0.0f);//left middle point
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);//Green
    glVertex3f(-0.3f, -0.3f, 0.0f);//bottom left point
    glColor3f(0.53, 0.12, 0.47);//Purple
    glVertex3f(0.3f, -0.3f, 0.0f);//bottom right point
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);//red
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.3f, 0.0f);//middle right point
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();//Sends the Scene to the window

}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){
        glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to store the rotation angle in a global variable. This would then look like this:

```
global:
float angle = 0;

draw:
glRotate(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
...

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
        angle += A_VALUE_PER_CLICK;
}
```

Edit: Note, that that the above rotates whenever you click (as asked). If you want to rotate the object as long as the mouse is pressed you'll have to do it a little bit different:

```
global:
bool is_mouse_down = false;
float angle = 0;

draw:
if (is_mouse_down)
    angle += ANGLE_PER_FRAME;

glRotate(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
...

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            is_mouse_down = true;
        if (state == GLUT_UP)
            is_mouse_down = false;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: To spin about a specific point (in this case the center of the polygon [0, 0.2, 0]), one always has to translate this point to the origin, then rotate and then translate it back. This means one has to use something like this code (the signs might be flipped):

```
draw:
glTranslate(0, 0.2, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glRotate(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslate(0, -0.2, 0);

//Draw

glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as my pentagon is just spinning uncontrollably and it doesn't seem to be around its center either

Comment: Sorry. I'll overread the thing with the center. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Okay the first part works however the spin seems a bit random and when i added the part with glTranslatef and push matrix the pentagon started going off the scene with each click